# Can I put a tire of a different type on a cube bike?

Tags: tire

I bought recently a Cube Aim Race bike. A bike guy told me in the bike service shop that the quality of the machinery is 7/8 (7 out of 8, with 8 being the worst).

Componentry is Shimano, this is maybe beside the point. I was thinking of upgrading the tires from the original ones, which have very fat contact surface, with some tires that don't (which are slimmer). Is this ok to do on a Cube bike?

[image: From company website as per specs]

Specs:

- Frame: Aluminium Lite, AMF, Double Butted, Internal Cable Routing, Tapered Head Tube, Flat Mount Brake, SIC Mount, FM Kickstand Mount
- Suspension:  SR Suntour XCT Disc Fork, 100mm, Lockout
- Brake system: Clarks Clout 1, Hydr. Disc Brake PM/FM (180/160)
- Front derailleur: Shimano FD-M315, Top Swing, 31.8mm Clamp
- Rear Derailleur: Shimano RD-M3020, 8-Speed
- Shifters: Shimano SL-M315, Rapidfire-Plus
- Bottom bracket Thun Paso-ML, 73mm BSA
- Crankset: Shimano FC-M315, 36x22T, 170mm
- Cassette: Shimano CS-HG31, 11-34T
- Chain: KMC Z8.3
- Headset: CUBE FPH868, Semi-Integrated
- Stem: CUBE Peformance Stem Race, 31.8mm
- Handlebar: CUBE Rise Trail Bar, 680mm
- Grips: ACID React
- Rims: CUBE ZX20, 32H, Disc
- Front hub: Shimano HB-TX505, QR, Centerlock
- Rear hub: Shimano FH-TX505, QR, Centerlock
- Tyres: Schwalbe Smart Sam, Active, 2.25
- Saddle: Natural Fit Venec Lite
- Seat post: CUBE Performance Post, 27.2mm
- Pedals: ACID PP MTB

Weight: 14,3 kg and RRP/SRP 679 EUR

<sub>from https://www.cube.eu/de-en/cube-aim-race-black-n-azure/601400</sub>

Comment: I've added a bit of info on this model, based on the brand and model you gave.  If this is wrong please either roll back the edit or add the correct info for your bike.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to upgrade the tires

Comment: Schwalbe Smart Sam are good tyres. But of course, you can replace them with anything you like better. You may want to consider what you are going to use the bike for, since there is no best-for-everything - tyre.

Comment: This 100% depends on exactly what you're planning on doing with you bike and why you want to change.  If off road trails(by off road, I mean proper off road MTB trails), I would suggest the current 2.25 tyres would be the minimum.  If your using this as a commuter type thing where the majority of your riding is road/gravel path you could go down to something like a 1.95 tyre maybe but the difference in contact patch is tiny.  My advice would be to just run the current tyres out and replace them when appropriate.